# Disk Utility NFS mounts broken in 10.7.3?

Tags: nfs, osx-lion

My NFS mounts no longer function in Lion 10.7.3. Although all the mounts in Disk Utility verify OK, no files can be seen in the mountpoints. I can use NFS Manager successfully however.

Comment: Same problem to me. I tried via network connection ( command-K in finder, Disk utility and via Terminal: sudo mount -t nfs -o resvport,vers=4 remote_ip:/your_shared_folder local_folder ) I only see a verify OK and the local folder disappear until I remove the connection.

Comment: Here's a twist. I have an iMac and a macbook pro. Both using identical settings in Disk Utility NFS Mounts... iMac works fine, macbook pro not so much. On the macbook, I can connect via finder or calling mount on the command line. Go figure.